# Disabling doubleclick on Grooveshark

Tags: javascript, html, overlay

I am trying to make webpage that acts as jukebox, to use for parties. I want the webpage to load Grooveshark with a transparant overlay(or whatwver it takes) that traps double clicks, to prevent people from forcing their song in the front of playlist.
I other words, all clicks are passed on to Grooveshark except double clicks.

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a third party service is very difficult.  "Stealing" a third-party service without credit is illegal.  Unless grooveshark has an api, I would strongly not recommend doing this.

Comment: I was no aware that it was considered stealing, so that you for telling me that!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's possible without them allowing it, since it's developed in Flash. On other services like snoost.com it may be possible, but I am not sure about gs.